# Windows Server Containers in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)

Tags: windows, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to run Windows containers in GKE.
Is it possible to use Windows Server Containers OS in Google Kubernetes Engine?

I see Windows Server Containers OS is available in Compute Engine and seems that Kubernetes support is [available](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/01/kubernetes-v19-beta-windows-support/) for Windows.

Comment: Windows is currently not supported on Google Kubernetes Engine. Kubernetes support for Windows is not stable or mature enough.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to run Windows containers, but only as a container in a Compute Engine VM instance.
I would refer you to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-run-windows-containers-on-compute-engine) in the GCP blog. Please be aware that there a few [known issues](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/#windows_known_issues) that you should read before deploying Windows containers in Windows VM instances.

For GKE, there is currently a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/110213558). Other customers have asked to include future support for Windows containers in GKE. This is a request through official means. Google will consider the need based on its feasibility, or the number of customers who ask for it, but they can't guarantee an implementation or provide you with an ETA for it.